# Converting XML file to another XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

XML file 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rentalProperties>
    <property contact ="1">
        <type>House </type>
        <price>420</price>
        <address>
            <streetNo>1</streetNo>
            <street>Wavell Street</street>
            <suburb>Box Hill</suburb>
            <state>VIC</state>
            <zipcode>3128</zipcode> 
        </address>
        <numberOfBedrooms>3</numberOfBedrooms>
        <numberOfBathrooms>1</numberOfBathrooms> 
        <garage>1</garage>   
    </property>
```

XML file 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rentalProperties>
    <property contact ="1">
        <type>House </type>
        <price>420</price>
        <address>1 wavell street,Box Hill,VIC,Australia</address>
        <numberOfBedrooms>3</numberOfBedrooms>
        <numberOfBathrooms>1</numberOfBathrooms> 
        <garage>1</garage>     
    </property>
```

How should i convert xml file 1 to xml fle 2 using xslt?
i want to represent the address as the single line and add a new attribute [country- Australia] to end of the line. i did the rest of it . i'm struggling with address line

XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rentalProperties>
            <property>
                <xsl:attribute name="contact"><xsl:value-of select='@contact'/></xsl:attribute>    
                <type><xsl:value-of select="type"/></type>
                <price><xsl:value-of select="price"/></price>
                <numberOfBedrooms><xsl:value-of select="numberOfBedrooms"/></numberOfBedrooms>
                <numberOfBathrooms><xsl:value-of select="numberOfBathrooms"/></numberOfBathrooms>
                <garage><xsl:value-of select="garage"/></garage>    
            </property>    
        </rentalProperties>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 32):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="address">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(streetNo, ' ', street, ',',
           suburb,',', state,', Australia')
   "/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="address/node()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<rentalProperties>
    <property contact ="1">
        <type>House </type>
        <price>420</price>
        <address>
            <streetNo>1</streetNo>
            <street>Wavell Street</street>
            <suburb>Box Hill</suburb>
            <state>VIC</state>
            <zipcode>3128</zipcode>
        </address>
        <numberOfBedrooms>3</numberOfBedrooms>
        <numberOfBathrooms>1</numberOfBathrooms>
        <garage>1</garage>
    </property>
</rentalProperties>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<rentalProperties>
   <property contact="1">
      <type>House </type>
      <price>420</price>
      <address>1 Wavell Street,Box Hill,VIC, Australia</address>
      <numberOfBedrooms>3</numberOfBedrooms>
      <numberOfBathrooms>1</numberOfBathrooms>
      <garage>1</garage>
   </property>
</rentalProperties>
```

**Explanation**: Using and overriding the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

Comment: Is it possible to also include the xml header in the output: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

Comment: @mgouin, It is called "XML declaration". Yes, just remove the `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` attribute from the `<xsl:output>` instruction

Answer (score 4):

You could introduce a new template for the address block using

```
<xsl:template match="address">
    <xsl:value-of select="streetNo" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="street" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="suburb" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="state" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="zipcode" />
</xsl:template>
```

and call it with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="address" />
```

before the `<numberOfBedrooms>` element. This can also be done using the `concat` function, whereas the correct syntax I don't remember right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
<address>
    <xsl:for-each select="address/*">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>, 
    </xsl:for-each>
    Australia
</address>
```

This loops over all the children of the address tag in xml1.

Answer (score -3):

```
<rentalProperties>
    <property contact="1">
        <type>House </type>
        <price>420</price>
        <address>1 Wavell Street,Box Hill,VIC,3128</address>
        <numberOfBedrooms>3</numberOfBedrooms>
        <numberOfBathrooms>1</numberOfBathrooms> 
        <garage>1</garage>   
    </property>
</rentalProperties>
```

Comment: Code-only answers can almost always be improved by adding a few explanatory sentences; you can [edit] your answer to do so.

Comment: What's the solution here?