# XSLT transformation for grouping elements

Tags: xml

I have the below requirement where my input XML is as below

```
<data>
    <POnumber> 11111</POnumber>
    <deliverynumber> 12345</deliverynumber>
    <statuscode> 001</statuscode>
    <productid> TV</productid>
    <quantity> 23</quantity>
</data>
<data>
    <POnumber> 11111</POnumber>
    <deliverynumber> 12345</deliverynumber>
    <statuscode> 001</statuscode>
    <productid> Mobile</productid>
    <quantity> 50</quantity>
</data>
<data>
    <POnumber> 23423</POnumber>
    <deliverynumber> 234242</deliverynumber>
    <statuscode> 005</statuscode>
    <productid> dvd</productid>
    <quantity> 10</quantity>
</data>
```

***The output XML should be***

```
<data>
    <POnumber> 11111</POnumber>
    <deliverynumber> 12345</deliverynumber>
    <statuscode> 001</statuscode>
    <product>
        <id>TV</id>
        <quantity>23</quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>Mobile</id>
        <quantity>50</quantity>
    </product>    
</data> 
<data>
    <POnumber> 23423</POnumber>
    <deliverynumber>234242</deliverynumber>
    <statuscode> 005</statuscode>
    <product>
        <id>dvd</id>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
    </product>
</data>
```

Can we achieve the above with XSLT transformation? If So please help, I am new to XSLT. We should group products id and quantity within the data node, if POnumber, deliverynumber and statuscode elements find their corressponding match.

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002772/converting-xml-file-to-another-xml-file-using-xslt